# How do I convert a 2X2 matrix to 4X4 matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat, tiling

I need some help in converting a 2X2 matrix to a 4X4 matrix in the following manner:

```
A = [2 6;
     8 4]
```

should become:

```
B = [2 2 6 6;
     2 2 6 6;
     8 8 4 4;
     8 8 4 4]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = [2 6; 8 4];
% arbitrary 2x2 input matrix

B = repmat(A,2,2);
% replicates rows & columns but not in the way you want

B = B([1 3 2 4], :);
% swaps rows 2 and 3

B = B(:, [1 3 2 4]);
% swaps columns 2 and 3, and you're done!
```

Comment: Nice! I thought there should be some way to do this with repmat and column and row swapping, but my brain is still half-asleep.

Comment: Solution by gnovice using Kroneker KRON function is better - it is more straightforward and clear - "intentional programming"

Comment: I like Martijn's answer better but that's just me.

Comment: With respect to all the indexing-based solutions, I actually prefer Edric's (which is a generalized form of las3rjock's edit).

Comment: The mathematical operation in question is called "Kronecker product"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product. The solution by gnovice does exactly this, directly. Other solutions, whatsoever clever, are detours.

Comment: Kronecker product is more general and allows multiplication. OP wanted to replicate matrix elements to form a block matrix. KRON function documentation, IMHO, is confusing and its use is less clear for this purpose. But we can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 23):

In newer versions of MATLAB (R2015a and later) the easiest way to do this is using the [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function:

```
B = repelem(A, 2, 2);
```

For older versions, a short alternative to the other (largely) indexing-based solutions is to use the functions [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) and [`ones`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html):

```
>> A = [2 6; 8 4];
>> B = kron(A, ones(2))

B =

     2     2     6     6
     2     2     6     6
     8     8     4     4
     8     8     4     4
```

Comment: shorter, although for generalization to large matrices, there's unnecessary multiplication that may slow things down.

Comment: @Jason S: True, but for larger matrices you would also have to do quite a bit more work in generating the indices needed by the other solutions here.

Answer (score 12):

Can be done even easier than Jason's solution:

```
B = A([1 1 2 2], :);  % replicate the rows
B = B(:, [1 1 2 2]);  % replicate the columns
```

Comment: One-liner: A = [2 6; 8 4]; B = A([1 1 2 2], [1 1 2 2]);

Answer (score 9):

Here's one more solution:

```
A = [2 6; 8 4];
B = A( ceil( 0.5:0.5:end ), ceil( 0.5:0.5:end ) );
```

which uses indexing to do everything and doesn't rely on the size or shape of A.

Comment: that is bizarre! somehow the "end" keyword knows about matrix A even though it's an argument to ceil(). I have no idea how that works but it does.

Comment: I have no idea how it does it either, but it's handy!

Comment: crazy, ugly and the most beautiful solution at the same time

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
A = [2 6; 8 4];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:2);
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(0.5:0.5:2);
B = interp2(X,Y,A,XI,YI,'nearest');
```

This is just two-dimensional nearest-neighbor interpolation of A(x,y) from x,y ∈ {1,2} to x,y ∈ {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2}.

**Edit**: Springboarding off of Jason S and Martijn's solutions, I think this is probably the shortest and clearest solution:

```
A = [2 6; 8 4];
B = A([1 1 2 2], [1 1 2 2]);
```

Comment: will this work for any generic 2X2 matrix or is only specific to this 2X2 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method based on simple indexing that works for an arbitrary matrix. We want each element to be expanded to an MxN submatrix:

```
A(repmat(1:end,[M 1]),repmat(1:end,[N 1]))
```

Example:

```
>> A=reshape(1:6,[2,3])

A =

     1     3     5
     2     4     6

>> A(repmat(1:end,[3 1]),repmat(1:end,[4 1]))

ans =

     1     1     1     1     3     3     3     3     5     5     5     5
     1     1     1     1     3     3     3     3     5     5     5     5
     1     1     1     1     3     3     3     3     5     5     5     5
     2     2     2     2     4     4     4     4     6     6     6     6
     2     2     2     2     4     4     4     4     6     6     6     6
     2     2     2     2     4     4     4     4     6     6     6     6
```

To see how the method works, let's take a closer look at the indexing. We start with a simple row vector of consecutive numbers

```
>> m=3; 1:m

ans =

     1     2     3
```

Next, we extend it to a matrix, by repeating it M times in the first dimension

```
>> M=4; I=repmat(1:m,[M 1])

I =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```

If we use a matrix to index an array, then the matrix elements are used consecutively in the standard Matlab order:

```
>> I(:)

ans =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     2
     3
     3
     3
     3
```

Finally, when indexing an array, the 'end' keyword evaluates to the size of the array in the corresponding dimension. As a result, in the example the following are equivalent:

```
>> A(repmat(1:end,[3 1]),repmat(1:end,[4 1]))
>> A(repmat(1:2,[3 1]),repmat(1:3,[4 1]))
>> A(repmat([1 2],[3 1]),repmat([1 2 3],[4 1]))
>> A([1 2;1 2;1 2],[1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3])
>> A([1 1 1 2 2 2],[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3])
```

Answer (score -4):

There is a Reshape() function that allows you to do this...

For example:

```
reshape(array, [64, 16])
```

And you can find a great video tutorial [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/03/13/reshape-a-matrix-without-using-a-for-loop/)

Cheers

Comment: reshape will not work for this--it requires that the input and output matrices have the same number of elements.

Comment: thanks for a quick one but i think for reshape the number of elements must not change. Here i have a 2X2 matrix ie 4 elements and i want to make a 4X4 matrix so 16 elements.No of elements are different. Wat to do?

Comment: Are you desiring the 'Reshape' process to add relevant element data in the newly-created space?