# Element-wise array replication in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat, run-length-encoding, elementwise-operations

Let's say I have a one-dimensional array:

`a = [1, 2, 3];`

Is there a built-in Matlab function that takes an array and an integer `n` and replicates each
element of the array n times?

For example calling `replicate(a, 3)` should return `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`.

Note that this is not at all the same as `repmat`.  I can certainly implement `replicate` by doing `repmat` on each element and concatenating the result, but I am wondering if there is a built in function that is more efficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**As of R2015a**, there is a [built-in and documented function to do this, `repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

> `repelem` Replicate elements of an array.
>           `W = repelem(V,N)`, with vector `V` and scalar `N`, creates a vector `W` where each element of `V` is repeated `N` times.

The second argument can also be a vector of the same length as `V` to specify the number of replications for each element.  For 2D replication:

```
B = repelem(A,N1,N2)
```

No need for `kron` or other tricks anymore!

**UPDATE:** For a performance comparison with other speedy methods, please see the Q&A [Repeat copies of array elements: Run-length decoding in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29084077/2778484).

Comment: How did you know this before R2015a was out?!

Comment: @LuisMendo Pre-release.  I love reading release notes almost as much as accumarray.  :). But I immediately deleted my answer an then undeleted it on release day so as not to break the terms of the pre-release.

Answer (score 21):

I'm a fan of the [KRON](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html) function:

```
>> a = 1:3;
>> N = 3;
>> b = kron(a,ones(1,N))

b =

    1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```

You can also look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643477/how-do-i-convert-a-2x2-matrix-to-4x4-matrix-in-matlab) (which dealt with replicating elements of 2-D matrices) to see some of the other solutions involving matrix indexing. Here's one such solution (inspired by [Edric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643477/how-do-i-convert-a-2x2-matrix-to-4x4-matrix-in-matlab/1643959#1643959)):

```
>> b = a(ceil((1:N*numel(a))/N))

b =

    1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```

Comment: what a nice solution, but what about if N be a matrix of frequency of elements of a, means that each element of N is correspond with one element of a?

Comment: @ghedas: That's addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1975772/52738), if you hadn't yet seen it.

Answer (score 20):

```
a = [1 2 3];
N = 3;

b = reshape(repmat(a,N,1), 1, [])
```

Comment: unlike `kron`, this solution is purely memory management, and does not drag multiplication into it.

Answer (score 3):

```
>> n=3;
>> a(floor((0:size(a,2)*n-1)/n)+1)

ans =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 3):

Some exotic alternatives. Admittedly more funny than useful:

1. Assign the (first) result of `meshgrid` to a vector:

   ```
   b = NaN(1,numel(a)*n); %// pre-shape result
   b(:) = meshgrid(a,1:n);
   ```
2. Build a matrix that multiplied by `a` gives the result:

   ```
   b = a * fliplr(sortrows(repmat(eye(numel(a)),n,1))).';
   ```
3. Use `ind2sub` to generate the indices:

   ```
   [~, ind] = ind2sub([n 1],1:numel(a)*n);
   b = a(ind);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the image processing toolbox, there is another alternative:

```
N = 3;
imresize(a, [1 N*numel(a)],'nearest')
```

Comment: Actually, your code is wrong. It should be `imresize(a, [1 N*numel(a)],'nearest')`, with an `N`, not a `2`. When you correct this, your solution is actually about 3 times **slower** than the KRON solution (and 5 times slower than the indexing solution `a(ceil((1:N*numel(a))/N))`).

Answer (score 1):

```
% To get b = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
N = 3;
a = [1 2 3];
temp_a = a(ones(N,1),:);
b = reshape(temp_a,1,numel(temp_a));

% To get b = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
N = 3;
a = [1 2 3];
temp_a = a(ones(N,1),:);
b = reshape(temp_a',1,numel(temp_a));
```