# Repeat copies of array elements: Run-length decoding in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, repeat, run-length-encoding

I'm trying to insert multiple values into an array using a 'values' array and a 'counter' array. For example, if:

```
a=[1,3,2,5]
b=[2,2,1,3]
```

I want the output of some function

```
c=somefunction(a,b)
```

to be

```
c=[1,1,3,3,2,5,5,5]
```

Where a(1) recurs b(1) number of times, a(2) recurs b(2) times, etc...

Is there a built-in function in MATLAB that does this? I'd like to avoid using a for loop if possible. I've tried variations of 'repmat()' and 'kron()' to no avail.

This is basically [`Run-length encoding`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Problem Statement

We have an array of values, `vals` and runlengths, `runlens`:

```
vals     = [1,3,2,5]
runlens  = [2,2,1,3]
```

We are needed to repeat each element in `vals` times each corresponding element in `runlens`. Thus, the final output would be:

```
output = [1,1,3,3,2,5,5,5]
```

### Prospective Approach

One of the fastest tools with MATLAB is [`cumsum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) and is very useful when dealing with vectorizing problems that work on irregular patterns. In the stated problem, the irregularity comes with the different elements in `runlens`.

Now, to exploit `cumsum`, we need to do two things here: Initialize an array of `zeros` and place "appropriate" values at "key" positions over the zeros array, such that after "`cumsum`" is applied, we would end up with a final array of repeated `vals` of `runlens` times.

**Steps:** Let's number the above mentioned steps to give the prospective approach an easier perspective:

1) Initialize zeros array: What must be the length? Since we are repeating `runlens` times, the length of the zeros array must be the summation of all `runlens`.

2) Find key positions/indices: Now these key positions are places along the zeros array where each element from `vals` start to repeat.
Thus, for `runlens  = [2,2,1,3]`, the key positions mapped onto the zeros array would be:

```
[X 0 X 0 X X 0 0] % where X's are those key positions.
```

3) Find appropriate values: The final nail to be hammered before using `cumsum` would be to put "appropriate" values into those key positions. Now, since we would be doing `cumsum` soon after, if you think closely, you would need a `differentiated` version of `values` with [`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), so that `cumsum` on those would **bring back our `values`**. Since these differentiated values would be placed on a zeros array at places separated by the `runlens` distances, after using `cumsum` we would have each `vals` element repeated `runlens` times as the final output.

**Solution Code**

Here's the implementation stitching up all the above mentioned steps -

```
% Calculate cumsumed values of runLengths. 
% We would need this to initialize zeros array and find key positions later on.
clens = cumsum(runlens)

% Initalize zeros array
array = zeros(1,(clens(end)))

% Find key positions/indices
key_pos = [1 clens(1:end-1)+1]

% Find appropriate values
app_vals = diff([0 vals])

% Map app_values at key_pos on array
array(pos) = app_vals

% cumsum array for final output
output = cumsum(array)
```

**Pre-allocation Hack**

As could be seen that the above listed code uses pre-allocation with zeros. Now, according to this [UNDOCUMENTED MATLAB blog on faster pre-allocation](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance), one can achieve much faster pre-allocation with -

```
array(clens(end)) = 0; % instead of array = zeros(1,(clens(end)))
```

**Wrapping up: Function Code**

To wrap up everything, we would have a compact function code to achieve this run-length decoding like so -

```
function out = rle_cumsum_diff(vals,runlens)
clens = cumsum(runlens);
idx(clens(end))=0;
idx([1 clens(1:end-1)+1]) = diff([0 vals]);
out = cumsum(idx);
return;
```

### Benchmarking

**Benchmarking Code**

Listed next is the benchmarking code to compare runtimes and speedups for the stated `cumsum+diff` approach in this post over the [other `cumsum-only` based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975835/3293881) on `MATLAB 2014B`-

```
datasizes = [reshape(linspace(10,70,4).'*10.^(0:4),1,[]) 10^6 2*10^6]; %
fcns = {'rld_cumsum','rld_cumsum_diff'}; % approaches to be benchmarked

for k1 = 1:numel(datasizes)
    n = datasizes(k1); % Create random inputs
    vals = randi(200,1,n);
    runs = [5000 randi(200,1,n-1)]; % 5000 acts as an aberration
    for k2 = 1:numel(fcns) % Time approaches  
        tsec(k2,k1) = timeit(@() feval(fcns{k2}, vals,runs), 1);
    end
end

figure,      % Plot runtimes
loglog(datasizes,tsec(1,:),'-bo'), hold on
loglog(datasizes,tsec(2,:),'-k+')
set(gca,'xgrid','on'),set(gca,'ygrid','on'),
xlabel('Datasize ->'), ylabel('Runtimes (s)')
legend(upper(strrep(fcns,'_',' '))),title('Runtime Plot')

figure,      % Plot speedups
semilogx(datasizes,tsec(1,:)./tsec(2,:),'-rx')        
set(gca,'ygrid','on'), xlabel('Datasize ->')
legend('Speedup(x) with cumsum+diff over cumsum-only'),title('Speedup Plot')
```

Associated function code for `rld_cumsum.m`:

```
function out = rld_cumsum(vals,runlens)
index = zeros(1,sum(runlens));
index([1 cumsum(runlens(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;
out = vals(cumsum(index));
return;
```

**Runtime and Speedup Plots**

[image]

[image]

### Conclusions

The proposed approach seems to be giving us a noticeable speedup over the `cumsum-only` approach, which is about **3x**!

**Why is this new `cumsum+diff` based approach better than the previous `cumsum-only` approach?**

Well, the essence of the reason lies at the final step of the `cumsum-only` approach that needs to map the "cumsumed" values  into `vals`. In the new `cumsum+diff` based approach, we are doing `diff(vals)` instead for which MATLAB is processing only `n` elements (where n is the number of runLengths) as compared to the mapping of `sum(runLengths)` number of elements for the `cumsum-only` approach and this number must be many times more than `n` and therefore the noticeable speedup with this new approach!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I think it may be one of the most thorough and well explained I've ever gotten on SO.

Comment: Nice optimization!  Out of curiosity, where does the built-in MATLAB function fit on the curve?  It might be useful to add it as a baseline.

Comment: @chappjc Thanks! Well that's the issue really, don't have access to `MATLAB 2015A`! Looking for volunteers on that, as stated in the bounty comment! :)

Comment: @Doresoom Glad to be of help on this! Seems like run-length decoding is quite useful and this `cumsum+diff` trick struck me recently!

Comment: @Divakar Oh, I see. Didn't read that. :) If a get a chance, I'll run it today.  But I can say now that it's not M-code backed, pure built-in or Mex.

Comment: @chappjc Would be interesting to see how it performs against these cumsum's ones then! I think  a CW answer would be suited for the benchmarks.

Comment: `rle_cumsum_diff` is much faster than MATLAB's `repelem`.  Well done!  Also, `repelem` has trouble with large data sizes, and gets much slower than even `rld_cumsum`.  I'll put the graphs in a CW shortly.

Comment: @chappjc Very kool! I made a slight typo there, the function must be named as `rld_cumsum_diff` instead of `rle_cumsum_diff`, because the plots would get the legends accordingly. RLD for run-length decoding that is.

Comment: @Divakar Good idea! It seems so obvious now :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, this "optimization" wasn't possible with the earlier generalised run-length decoding we did sometime ago covering cell arrays, because the `diff` won't work on them!

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I immediately remembered that question. I've suggested chappjc to add to the benchmarking a stripped-down version of the fastest answer there. On my R2014b it's slower, though. In fact, your approach looks hard to beat!

Comment: @LuisMendo In fact, I would love to see more approaches being added in this CW answer, but without those cell arrays considerations and zero runlengths, just to keep their essence!

Comment: Interesting idea. Even beats the new builtin! It has its downsides though, as it won't work correctly with integer types e.g. `vals = int8([120,-120])` or doubles with large variance `vals = [1e16, 1]` or `Inf`s/`Nan`s.

Comment: @knedlsepp Thanks! Yup because of `diff()`, good find on corner cases!

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. It doesn't seem to support zeros in runlens though, e.g. `rld_cumsum(1:4, [0 0 3 0]) = [1 1 1 2]` instead of the expected `[3 3 3]`. Bit of an edge case, but thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @PaulCalcraft Thanks! Yeah I gotta fix that. Appreciate you testing out!

Comment: One of the last lines under the heading *"Solution Code"* is:  `array(pos)=app_vals;`, It should be: `array(key_pos)=app_vals;`

Comment: @SardarUsama Yup and that handling zero repeat cases are to be updated for. Thanks for pointing it out! Would update soon, hopefully.

Answer (score 21):

Benchmarks

**Updated for R2015b**: `repelem` now fastest for all data sizes.

---

Tested functions:

1. MATLAB's built-in [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function that was added in R2015a
2. gnovice's `cumsum` solution ([`rld_cumsum`](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/bd440ae2922f91082f04))
3. Divakar's `cumsum`+`diff` solution ([`rld_cumsum_diff`](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/fc9047dae632da6fc65c))
4. knedlsepp's `accumarray` solution ([`knedlsepp5cumsumaccumarray`](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/7db48721c09c29f607e9)) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28615814/2778484)
5. Naive loop-based implementation ([`naive_jit_test.m`](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/b92dc0ffdd2366341c4b)) to test the just-in-time compiler

Results of [`test_rld.m`](https://gist.github.com/chappjc/a0f0634a5be68df0252c) on R2015**b**:

[image: repelem time]

Old timing plot using R2015**a** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oCxQ.png).

**Findings**:

- `repelem` is always the fastest by roughly a factor of 2.
- `rld_cumsum_diff` is consistently faster than `rld_cumsum`.
- <s>`repelem` is fastest for small data sizes (less than about 300-500 elements)</s>
- <s>`rld_cumsum_diff` becomes significantly faster than `repelem` around 5 000 elements</s>
- <s>`repelem` becomes slower than `rld_cumsum` somewhere between 30 000 and 300 000 elements</s>
- `rld_cumsum` has roughly the same performance as `knedlsepp5cumsumaccumarray`
- `naive_jit_test.m` has nearly constant speed and on par with `rld_cumsum` and `knedlsepp5cumsumaccumarray` for smaller sizes, a little faster for large sizes

[image]

Old rate plot using R2015**a** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBRaG.png).

**Conclusion**

Use `repelem` <s>below about 5 000 elements and the `cumsum`+`diff` solution above</s>.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting processing rate plot!

Comment: @Divakar Thanks.  It was a little hard to see the transitions in the `loglog` plot of runtimes.

Comment: It would be nice to add the fastest function from [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28502898/2586922) here, namely `knedlsepp5cumsumaccumarray`. To be fair, it would have to be stripped down to `V = cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1; runLengths(:)]), 1));
V = values(V(1:end-1));` (no checking etc). On my R2014b it's slower, though

Comment: My code is basically the same as *gnovice*'s, as *Divakar* pointed me to it when researching this topic. The only difference is the use of `accumarray` instead of `index(...) = 1`, to make his code work when the `runLengths` array includes zeros. That's why those perform quite similarly.

Comment: @knedlsepp I saw, and I approved!  :D

Comment: @chappjc Thanks for adding JIT and knedlsepp's solutions!

Comment: Seems like `for` will be sitting at the cool kids' table after all!

Comment: @knedlsepp It almost pains me to write code like that in MATLAB, but that's shows how much it has improved...  It's like writing in C.  Very odd.

Comment: @Divakar Hey, thanks for the bounty award!  I've been on vacation and have't really looked closely at my profile. A nice surprise!

Answer (score 16):

There's no built-in function I know of, but here's one solution:

```
index = zeros(1,sum(b));
index([1 cumsum(b(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;
c = a(cumsum(index));
```

### Explanation:

A vector of zeroes is first created of the same length as the output array (i.e. the sum of all the replications in `b`). Ones are then placed in the first element and each subsequent element representing where the start of a new sequence of values will be in the output. The cumulative sum of the vector `index` can then be used to index into `a`, replicating each value the desired number of times.

For the sake of clarity, this is what the various vectors look like for the values of `a` and `b` given in the question:

```
        index = [1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
cumsum(index) = [1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4]
            c = [1 1 3 3 2 5 5 5]
```

---

**EDIT:** For the sake of completeness, there *is* another alternative using [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), but this seems to take anywhere from 20-100 times longer to run than the above solution with vectors up to 10,000 elements long:

```
c = arrayfun(@(x,y) x.*ones(1,y),a,b,'UniformOutput',false);
c = [c{:}];
```

Comment: Thanks gnovice! This code is about 15x faster than what I had before.

Answer (score 12):

There is finally (as of **R2015a**) a built-in and documented function to do this, [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html).  The following syntax, where the second argument is a vector, is relevant here:

> `W = repelem(V,N)`, with vector `V` and vector `N`, creates a vector `W` where element `V(i)` is repeated `N(i)` times.

Or put another way, "Each element of `N` specifies the number of times to repeat the corresponding element of `V`."

Example:

```
>> a=[1,3,2,5]
a =
     1     3     2     5
>> b=[2,2,1,3]
b =
     2     2     1     3
>> repelem(a,b)
ans =
     1     1     3     3     2     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 3):

The performance problems in MATLAB's built-in `repelem` have been fixed as of R2015b. I have run the `test_rld.m` program from chappjc's post in R2015b, and `repelem` is now faster than other algorithms by about a factor 2:

[image: Updated plot comparing repelem execution time of different methods]
[image: Speedup of repelem over cumsum+diff (about a factor 2)]

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I've updated my CW post.  I never though about it as being a performance _problem_, otherwise I would have submitted a bug report to you.  But great news!