# How to obtain a random sample from a categorical distribution using Matlab's rand()?

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate samples according to a simple categorical probability distribution, e.g.

```
p(A) = 0.1
p(B) = 0.5
p(C) = 0.25
p(D) = 0.15
```

Using rand(), which uniformly generates samples in (0,1] what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted random numbers in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just check if the random number is less than the probability of each category, <strike>in order of increasing probability</strike>:

```
value = rand()
if value < p(A) 
    return A
if value < p(A)+p(B) 
    return B
if value < p(A)+p(B)+P(C) 
    return C
else            
    return D
```

<strike>I can't really tell you the best way to get them in order without knowing more about your code.</strike> If you have only a small number of cases that won't be changing, it might be easiest just to hard-code it once by hand as I've done above.

Edit: now that I think about it, since we're accumulating the probabilities, it doesn't really matter what order they're in. I've adjusted my code accordingly.

Edit edit: I think this is essentially how [randsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/randsample.html) works.

Comment: Yeah, basically I am not in a loop and keep a "current" sum of probabilities and once the sum is above the random "value", I chose this event.