# Sampling Random Columns In Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a matrix that I want to select *t* random columns from for a new matrix in Octave randomly but I want my random selection to be weighted with a proportionality based on a singular value decomposition of the matrix. So essentially I want to select *t* random columns with a probability that is determined prior to the selection. Is there a way to do this in Octave/Matlab?

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some row vector of weights, `W`, (or in your case probably some function of the eigenvalues of the matrix), you should first create a vector representing the normalized cumulative sum of the weights as follows:

```
cumNormW = cumsum(W)./sum(W);
```

The values of `cumNormW` should now be monotonically increasing and should range from `W(1)` to `1`.

Next you'll want to take draws from a uniform distribution over `[0,1]`

```
randVal = rand(1);
```

You will use this random value to look up the appropriate column you have just randomly selected.  Finally, you want to find the first index of your cumulative normalized weight vector.

```
randCol = find(cumNormW <= randVal, 1, 'last')
```

This provides you with your final random column selection.

Now if you want to ensure that you select `t` *different* columns, you'll need to keep track of previous values of `randCol` and simply re-iterate the above above `randVal`, `randCol` steps until you produce a yet unchosen column.

---

*Example*

Let's say you have a matrix with 4 columns and you have calculated the eigenvalues for that matrix and stored them in W.  We'll assume that columns correspond to eigenvectors and you want to choose a column with probability proportional to that column's eigenvalue compared to the sum of eigenvalues.

```
W = [4 3 2 1];
```

After normalizing, you get `cumNormW = [0.40 0.70 0.90 1];`

As you can see, you have a significantly higher probability of drawing a number that results in choosing the first column (`randVal <= 0.4') than the last column ('0.9 < randVal <= 1')

You draw a random number via `rand(1)` and for this example, lets say `randVal = 0.82`.  Using the final `randCol` step, for this iteration you would get `randCol = 3`.