# draw random number following a custom distribution

Tags: performance, matlab, random, distribution, probability

I need to draw random numbers following a distribution I chose.

Example: draw 7 numbers from 1 to 7 with those probabilities:

- 1: 0.3
- 2: 0.2
- 3: 0.15
- 4: 0.15
- 5: 0.1
- 6: 0.05
- 7: 0.05

Since in my actual application I need to draw potentially 1000 numbers I need this to be as much efficient as possible (ideally linear).
I know there is a function in MATLAB that draws random numbers from a normal distribution; is there any way to adapt it?

Comment: See also [Weighted random numbers in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think you can use [randsample](http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/randsample.html) too from Statistics Toolbox as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab).

```
%%// Replace 7 with 1000 for original problem
OUT = randsample([1:7], 7, true, [0.3 0.2 0.15 0.15 0.1 0.05 0.05])
```

Comment: I was just answering with this. +1

Comment: If you check the the distribution, it won't be the requested one.

Comment: @thewaywewalk The idea is to draw numbers with a certain probability from a custom distribution, not generate samples that have a specific distribution.  Note the OP's comments about the existing function to draw from a normal distribution.

Comment: +1 I keep forgetting about `randsample`

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = 1:7;
probs = [.3 .2 .15 .15 .1 .05 .05];
N = 1000; %// how many random numbers you want

cumProbs = cumsum(probs(:)); %// will be used as thresholds
r = rand(1,N); %// random numbers between 0 and 1
output = sum(bsxfun(@ge, r, cumProbs))+1; %// how many thresholds are exceeded
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gendist from matlab file exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34101-random-numbers-from-a-discrete-distribution/content/gendist.m

This generates 1000 random numbers:
`gendist([.3,.2,.15,.15,.1,.05,.05],1000,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html), you can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) like it does internally, just without all the fluff:

```
N = 100;
nums = 1:7;
p = [.3 .2 .15 .15 .1 .05 .05];

cdf = [0 cumsum(p(:).'/sum(p))]; cdf(end)=1; %' p is pdf
[~, isamps] = histc(rand(N,1),cdf);
out = nums(isamps);
```