# Sampling from a discrete set where each element has a corresponding density

Tags: matlab, sampling

Here is my problem in Matlab:

I have a set of integers e.g. `A={10,11,12,...,T}` with corresponding densities `P={p(10),p(11),P(12),...,P(T)}`. How do I randomly sample from `A` using the weights from `P`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted random numbers in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html), you can use [randsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html).

```
X = randsample(A, 1, true, P);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, found a earlier post that helped answer the question too. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab