# Improving on the efficiency of randsample in MATLAB for a Markov chain simulation.

Tags: matlab, random, markov-chains

I am using matlab to simulate an accumulation process with several random walks that accumulate towards threshold in parallel. To select which random walk will increase at time t, randsample is used. If the vector V represents the active random walks and vector P represents the probability with which each random walk should be selected then the call to randsample looks like this:

`randsample(V, 1, true, P);`

The problem is that the simulations are slow, and randsample is the bottleneck. Approximately 80% of the runtime is dedicated to resolving the randsample call.

Is there a relatively straightforward way to improve upon the efficiency of randsample? Are there other alternatives that might improve the speed?

Comment: related: [Weighted random numbers in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2977497)

Comment: @Amro Thanks for the link. It has given me the indication that `P` might not be normalized

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in the comments, the bottleneck is properly caused by the fact that you are sampling one value at a time, it would be faster if you vectorize the `randsample` call (of course I am assuming that the probabilities vector is constant).

Here is a quick benchmark:

```
function testRandSample()
    v = 1:5;
    w = rand(numel(v),1); w = w ./ sum(w);
    n = 50000;

    % timeit
    t(1) = timeit(@() func1(v, w, n));
    t(2) = timeit(@() func2(v, w, n));
    t(3) = timeit(@() func3(v, w, n));
    disp(t)

    % check distribution of samples (should be close to w)
    tabulate(func1(v, w, n))
    tabulate(func2(v, w, n))
    tabulate(func3(v, w, n))
    disp(w*100)
end


function s = func1(v, w, n)
    s = randsample(v, n, true, w);
end

function s = func2(v, w, n)
    [~,idx] = histc(rand(n,1), [0;cumsum(w(:))./sum(w)]);
    s = v(idx);
end

function s = func3(v, w, n)
    cw = cumsum(w) / sum(w);
    s = zeros(n,1);
    for i=1:n
        s(i) = find(rand() <= cw, 1, 'first');
    end
    s = v(s);

    %s = v(arrayfun(@(~)find(rand() <= cw, 1, 'first'), 1:n));
end
```

The output (annotated):

```
% measured elapsed times for func1/2/3 respectively
  0.0016    0.0015    0.0790

% distribution of random sample from func1
  Value    Count   Percent
      1     4939      9.88%
      2    15049     30.10%
      3     7450     14.90%
      4    11824     23.65%
      5    10738     21.48%

% distribution of random sample from func2
  Value    Count   Percent
      1     4814      9.63%
      2    15263     30.53%
      3     7479     14.96%
      4    11743     23.49%
      5    10701     21.40%

% distribution of random sample from func3
  Value    Count   Percent
      1     4985      9.97%
      2    15132     30.26%
      3     7275     14.55%
      4    11905     23.81%
      5    10703     21.41%

% true population distribution
    9.7959
   30.4149
   14.7414
   23.4949
   21.5529
```

As you can see, `randsample` is pretty well optimized. The bottleneck you observed in your code is probably due lack of vectorization as I explained.

To see how slow it can get, replace `func1` with a looped version sampling one value at-a-time:

```
function s = func1(v, w, n)
    s = zeros(n,1);
    for i=1:n
        s(i) = randsample(v, 1, true, w);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be faster:

```
find(rand <= cumsum(P), 1) %// gives the same as randsample(V, 1, true, P)
```

I'm assuming `P` are probabilities, i.e. their sum is `1`. Otherwise normalize `P`:

```
find(rand <= cumsum(P)/sum(P), 1) %// gives the same as randsample(V, 1, true, P)
```

If `P` is always the same, precompute `cumsum(P)/sum(P)` to save time:

```
cp = cumsum(P)/sum(P); %// precompute (just once)
find(rand <= cP, 1) %// gives the same as randsample(V, 1, true, P)
```

Comment: I think the bottleneck comes from the fact that the OP is sampling one value at a time in a loop of some kind. If `P` is constant, simply vectorize the call to `randsample` by pre-picking N values at once and storing the array. Then each time a new value is needed, simply index into the array. `randsample` is already optimized using `cumsum+histc` method as shown by woodchips answer in the related question I linked to.

Comment: P are indeed probabilities and are normalised. However, the size of P is not constant and varies between a vector size 1 and 4. However, each of the 4 possible values *are* constant. Vectorisation should still help in this case I expect?