# how to store 00 as 00 instead of 0 only

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

MATLAB stores `00` and `01` as `0` and `1` respectively. How can I make MATLAB store `00` as `00` and `01` as `01` instead of `0` and `1` only...here is my code.. I am talking about the statements with `<--` only..In fact I want to input the result as initial population(chromosome) to a genetic algorithm.

```
function [x]=abc()
r=randi([0 3],1,20);
for i=1:20 
       if r(i)==0
            x(i)=00; %// <--
        elseif r(i)==1 
            x(i)=01; %// <--
        elseif r(i)==2
           x(i)=10;
        elseif r(i)==3 
            ex(i)=11;
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: How about storing two columns in a matrix?

Comment: Or else as a string.

Comment: What do you mean by storing `00`? `0` and `00` is the same integer.

Comment: @Dev-iL can u please share code for this as i am totally new to matlab.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that a loop may not be the best way to go here...
Here are just a couple of options: **1)** define x as a cell `x={}`, and then you do `x{i} = [0,0]` (or `[0,1]` etc.); **2)** preallocate `x` as an `i-by-2` matrix (ex. `x(i,2)=0;` and in the `if` structure you just write `x(i,:) = [0,0]` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to store the binary representation of your numbers, so you can use the function [`dec2bin`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html)

and the best thing, you don't even need a loop ;)

```
r=randi([0 3],1,20);
x = dec2bin(r,2) ;

>> x
x =
10
00
11
11
10
11
10
01
...
```

Comment: thanks for the code...this is really useful for me.....i have one more question....Is is possible (in "randi()" function) to have more number of 3's compared to 2's...similarly more number of 2's compared to 1's and so on...i mean can we assign probabilities to them...e.g. probabilities like 0.4 to 3, 0.3 to 2, 0.2 to 1 and 0.1 to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Nice to know when we've been useful. As for assigning weights to the probability of occurrences, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab/2977602#2977602)