# Need alternative to randsample for probability vectors with 0s in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question similar to this one:
[Weighted random numbers in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab)

At this point, I use randsample in my program as follows:

```
T = [0 .5 .5; .5 0 .5; .5 .5 0]
choices = 1:3

for i = 1:3
    t(i) = transpose(randsample(choices,1,true,T(i,:)));
end
```

Thus `t(i)` describes for each person which neighbor they will select.

My `T` matrix, when read rowwise describes the probability of a person to select their neighbor. For example, the first row says the 1st person will select node 2 or 3 with 50% probability each. They cannot select his own node 1. As I scale up my model, they will always have equal probability of selecting a neighbor, 1/number of neighbors. I have hardcoded the T matrix here for brevity's sake.

I tried to use `histc` as suggested in the linked topic, but since there is always a `0` in each row of my `T` matrix, I don't think the cumulative sum accurately sets up bins for rows with a 0 in the middle (here the second row of `T`).

I also tried to use `bsxfun`, and I was able to get sensical output when looking at each row of my `T` matrix individually, but I failed to put it in a loop. I feel the solution may be here, but I'm not sure I fully understand how this function is operating in my context.

**So, does anybody have any ideas of how I can speed up my randsample function?** At the moment, I iterate it 10000x, and so it is a major bottleneck in my program. It works as I need it to, it's just far too slow.

Comment: Your question seems ok to me. But just in case, these are manuals on how to ask good questions: [ask], http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

So you want, for each person, to pick a neighbour among all other persons, with uniform probability.

I would do it this way. It should be pretty fast.

```
n = 7;                      %// number of persons
t = ceil((n-1)*rand(1,n));  %// step 1
t = t + (t>=(1:n));         %// step 2
```

For each `k`, the generated `t(k)` is randomly picked from the set {`1`, `2`, ..., `k-1`, `k+1`, ..., `n`} with uniform distribution. To achieve this, two steps are used:

1. A random value is picked from {`1`, ..., `n-1`};
2. If this value is greater than or equal to `k` it is incremented by `1`.