# Vectorised/faster form of datasample (statistics toolbox) - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I currently use `datasample` for weighted random selection from within a matrix whereby each element itself contains its weight (the frequency at which the datapoint will be chosen) in this form:

```
A = datasample(edgeL:edgeR,1,'Replace',false,'Weights',model(edgeL:edgeR));
```

This approach is rather slow. I am wondering if this is due to `datasample` itself or the fact that I choose a single value during each iteration of the above. The latter is needed because I am modifying the weights around each point as it is chosen and thus the entire distribution must be re-assessed during each iteration.

Is there a faster way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Try the second par of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2977602/2586922)

Comment: Thanks. This has improved my processing rates ~4.5x fold.

Comment: Did that solve your issue completely? Shall we close the question as duplicate then?