# Matlab vectorization of vector creation

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the creation of the following vector:

For example-
Let `A` be a vector `[5 3 2 1]`
And let B be a vector `[1 2 3 4]`

I would like `C` to be the vector `[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4]`

Meaning- each element `i` in `B` is duplicated `A(i)` times in `C`.

I haven't found a way to vectorize the creation of this, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Ronen

Comment: as well as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/matlab-array-manipulation (and many other linked ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach if `B` doesn't have any `zeros` -

```
C = nonzeros(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@le,[1:max(A)]',A),B))
```

---

**Approach #2**

A general case solution -

```
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:max(A)]',A) %//'
B_ext = bsxfun(@times,mask,B)
C = B_ext(mask)
```

---

**Approach #3**

`cumsum` based approach and must be pretty efficient one -

```
idx = [1 cumsum(A(1:end-1))+1] %// indices where each new B values start
C = zeros(sum(A),1) %// storage for output
C(idx) = diff([0 B]) %// put those values, but offseted
C = cumsum(C) %// finally get the output
```