# How to make elements of multiple vectors repeated by MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have 2 data vectors `d1 = [1 2 1 3 4]` and `d2 = [3 1 2 1]`, and 2 references `howMany1= [3 2 2 1 2]` and `howMany2 = [2 1 2 2]`. The elements of d1 and d2 are to be repeated according to the elements of howMany1 and howMany2: so d1(1) i.e. the first element of d1 should repeat 3 times,d1(2) should repeat 2 times and so on.. and the final result should be `d1_repeated = [1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 4 4]` and `d2_repeated = [3 3 1 2 2 1 1]`

How could I do that in MATLAB? I reviewed the a similar post in which one vector is being repeated, so I tried to do the same and made a for loop. Here is my code:

```
clear all
close all
clc
% data

d1 = [1 2 1 3 4];
d2 = [3 1 2 1];
howMany1 = [3 2 2 1 2]; % Determines how many times each index in IDX1 should be repeated.
howMany2 = [2 1 2 2];
d = {d1 d2}
howMany = {howMany1 howMany2}
Anew = cell(1,2)
for k = 1:2 % 2 data vectors     
Anew{1,k} = arrayfun(@(x) repmat(d{k}(x), howMany{k}(x), 1), 1:numel(d{k}), 'uni', 0);
Anew = vertcat(Anew{:});

end
```

but I receive the following error:

```
Error using vertcat

Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Then I tried to change the vert cat to horzcat, but I receive the repetitions as group of doubles:

```
Anew = 

  Columns 1 through 7

    [3x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [1]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [3]

  Column 8

    [2x1 double]
```

Im wondering what is the problem here? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate in the flag,  see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1975772/2778484.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by combining ismember and cumsum:

```
d1(cumsum(ismember(1:sum(howMany1),cumsum([1 howMany1]))))
```

**Breakdown**:

Compare `1:sum(howMany1)` with the cumulative sum of `howMany1`. This is a vector with 1 and 0 that shows the position of where the next value from d1 should start.

```
ismember(1:sum(howMany1),cumsum([1 howMany1]))
ans =
     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0
```

The cumulative sum of this gives a vector that looks like:

```
cumsum(ismember(1:sum(howMany1),cumsum([1 howMany1])))
ans =
     1     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     5     5
```

Now, this can be used as indices to `d1` when creating the d1_repeated.

```
d1(cumsum(ismember(1:sum(howMany1),cumsum([1 howMany1]))))
ans =
     1     1     1     2     2     1     1     3     4     4
```

Comment: Despite being a duplicate question, this is a novel answer.  Clever use of `ismember`!  +1