# Matlab - replicating arrays values according to occurrences array

Tags: arrays, matlab, replicate

For example, `A = [19 20 21 22 23 24 25];` `B = [2 0 3 0 0 0 2];`

How can we get a new array, repeating each value from B accordingly X times?

For example, answer here is: `[19 19 21 21 21 25 25]`.

Please note that I am only allowed to a `for` loop combined with a `repmat` call.

Comment: We cannot use any other "complex" matlab functions.. (only 1 loop, and basic matlab functions..).. No idea what numel/bsxfun is.. this question is from an exam, we are tried to figure it out, but there are no solutions.

Comment: Your link is very complicated :(

Comment: How do you define "basic" MATLAB functions? The link also provides `cumsum` based approach which could be easier to follow. Also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1975772/3293881) for a simple implementation with `cumsum`!

Comment: It is not possible by using only repmat or the for iteself?

Comment: Alright, so what did you try? Show your code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but something like:

A= [19 20 21 22 23 24 25];
B = [2 0 3 0 0 0 2];
    for i=1:length(a)
        sorted(i) = repmat(b,1,shows(i));
    end

I know the syntax is incorrect, but maybe a repmat :S

Comment: @Osh24: I recommend to create a new question including all these additional informations. Here the variable names don't match your example, at least `shows` is undefined.

Comment: @Osh24 Add those code details in the question and the edited question could be reopened then. You won't need post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only allowed to use `repmat` and a `for` loop, you can do the following:

```
S = []; 
for idx = 1 : length(B) 
    S = [S repmat(A(idx), 1, B(idx))]; 
end
```

`S` is initially a blank array, then for as many values as there are in `B` (or `A` since they're both equal in length), simply concatenate `S` with each value in `A` that is repeated by the corresponding number in `B`.  `S` will contain the output.

By running the above example, I get:

```
S =

    19    19    21    21    21    25    25
```

However, I highly recommend you use more vectorized approaches.  I'll leave that to you as an exercise.

Good luck!