# Element-wise Matrix Replication in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, replication, element

I have a 3 dimensional matrix. I want to replicate the matrix of size 8x2x9 to a specified number of times in the third dimension given by a vector say `[3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1]` so that the resultant matrix is of size 8x2x21. Is there any built-in MATLAB function (I'm running version 2014a) to do this similar to the newer `repelem` function, for matrices?

A simple example of what I need:

```
% Input:
A(:,:,1) = [1 2; 1 2];
A(:,:,2) = [2 3; 2 3];

% Function call:
A = callingfunction(A, 1, 1, [1 2]);

% Output:
A(:,:,1) = [1 2; 1 2];
A(:,:,2) = [2 3; 2 3];
A(:,:,3) = [2 3; 2 3];
```

Comment: This will not work in all MATLAB version. I think you need to make this clear

Comment: a sample of your input and expected output please.

Comment: edited my question for sample input, output @ha9u63ar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For R2015a and newer...

According to the documentation for [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) (first introduced in version R2015a), it can operate on matrices as well. I believe the following code should accomplish what you want (I can't test it because I have an older version):

```
newMat = repelem(mat, 1, 1, [3 2 1 1 5 4 2 2 1]);
```

### For pre-R2015a versions...

You can use one of the approaches from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1975772/52738) to replicate an index into the third dimension, then simply index your matrix with that. For example (adapting [Divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29079288/52738)):

```
vals = 1:size(mat, 3);
clens = cumsum([3 2 1 1 5 4 2 2 1]);
index = zeros(1, clens(end));
index([1 clens(1:end-1)+1]) = diff([0 vals]);
newMat = mat(:, :, cumsum(index));
```

You can then generalize this into a function to operate on multiple dimensions like `repelem` does:

```
function A = my_repelem(A, varargin)

  index = cell(1, nargin-1);
  for iDim = 1:nargin-1
    lens = varargin{iDim};
    if isscalar(lens)
      if (lens == 1)
        index{iDim} = ':';
        continue
      else
        lens = repmat(lens, 1, size(A, iDim));
      end
    end
    vals = 1:size(A, iDim);
    clens = cumsum(lens);
    index{iDim} = zeros(1, clens(end));
    index{iDim}([1 clens(1:end-1)+1]) = diff([0 vals]);
    index{iDim} = cumsum(index{iDim});
  end
  A = A(index{:});

end
```

And for your sample data, you would use it like so:

```
>> A(:,:,1) = [1 2; 1 2];
>> A(:,:,2) = [2 3; 2 3];
>> A = my_repelem(A, 1, 1, [1 2])

A(:,:,1) =

     1     2
     1     2

A(:,:,2) =

     2     3
     2     3

A(:,:,3) =

     2     3
     2     3
```

Comment: This is a version/toolbox specific feature. I think OP wants a more generic solution

Comment: @ha9u63ar Generic solution achieved.

Comment: @SanthanSalai      Could you please post your sample input and output?

Comment: Nice extension of it!