# Reordering a vector in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector in Matlab `B` of dimension `nx1` that contains the integers from `1` to `n` in a certain order, e.g. `n=6 B=(2;4;5;1;6;3)`.

I have a vector `A` of dimension `mx1` with `m>1` that contains the same integers in ascending order each one repeated an arbitrary number of times, e.g. `m=13` `A=(1;1;1;2;3;3;3;4;5;5;5;5;6)`.

I want to get `C` of dimension `mx1` in which the integers in `A` are reordered following the order in `B`. In the example, `C=(2;4;5;5;5;5;1;1;1;6;3;3;3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach with `ismember` and `sort` -

```
[~,idx] = ismember(A,B)
[~,sorted_idx] = sort(idx)
C = B(idx(sorted_idx))
```

---

If you are into one-liners, then another with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
C = B(nonzeros(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@eq,A,B.'),1:numel(B))))
```

Answer (score 3):

This requires just one `sort` and indexing:

```
ind = 1:numel(B);
ind(B) = ind;
C = B(sort(ind(A)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `repelem`, `accumarray`, `unique`

```
B=[2;4;5;1;6;3];
A=[1;1;1;2;3;3;3;4;5;5;5;5;6];

counts = accumarray(A,A)./unique(A);
repelem(B,counts(B));

%// or as suggested by Divakar 
%// counts = accumarray(A,1);
%// repelem(B,counts(B));
```

**PS: `repelem`** was introduced in **`R2015a`**. If you are using a prior version, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/repeat-copies-of-array-elements-run-length-decoding-in-matlab)

Comment: In case OP doesn't have access to 2015a for `repelem`, link it to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1975772/3293881)?

Comment: @Divakar y not? even i am using R2014a, i didn't test the last line LOL.

Comment: Think, you can do it in two steps: `counts = accumarray(A,1);
C= repelem(B,counts(B))`.

Comment: @Divakar, Thanks.. just noticed both `i` and `B` were same *face palm*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `hist`, but with a loop and expanding memory :(

```
y = hist(A, max(A))
reps = y(B);
C = [];
for nn = 1:numel(reps)
    C = [C; repmat(B(nn), reps(nn), 1)];
end
```