# MATLAB equating cell elements to array

Tags: matlab, cell

I'm trying to equate each element to an array which correspond to cell element.
To explain it more precisely, e.g

```
A    = {[1 1 1], [0 0 0 0 0], [1 1],[0 0 0 0 0]};
B    = [0 1 0 0];
```

So the thing I want is :

```
A= {[0 0 0],[1 1 1 1 1],[0 0],[0 0 0 0 0]};
```

Possible solution with for loop is :

```
for ii=1:length(A)
     A{ii}(:)=B(ii);
end
```

Is there any methode which does not use loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`repelem`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) and [`mat2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)

```
lens = cellfun(@numel, A);

out = mat2cell(repelem(B,lens).*ones(1,sum(lens)),1,lens)
```

**Note:**

1. `cellfun` is looping in disguise. But, here `cellfun` is used to
   find the number of elements alone. So this could be considered
   almost vectorised :P
2. `repelem` function is introduced in R2015a. You may not be able to
   run this in prior versions. Instead you may create your own custom `repelem` function. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29079288/2111163)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
A=cellfun(@(x, y) repmat(y, size(x)), A, num2cell(B), 'uni', 0)
```

This has the advantage that it handles matrices of any size or dimension in `A`. No assumption on being vector.