# MATLAB: Creating an array by repeating the index of a cell by the length of the cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell

I am using Matlab to create a cell array of data shown below. I would like to create a new array (output) where the *index* of the cell is repeated "x" times. Where "x" is equal to the length of that specific cell. I can do this with for loops, but can it be done with a simple function?

```
data = {[1,2,3], [4,5], [6], [7,8,9,10]}
% output = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4]
```

Comment: Please show your looped solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)  and [`repelem`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)

```
output = repelem(1:numel(data), cellfun(@numel, data));
```

but note that:

- `cellfun` is more or less the same as a loop;
- `repelem` was introduced in version R2015a.

Comment: [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/repeat-copies-of-array-elements-run-length-decoding-in-matlab) if `repelem` is not available

Answer (score 1):

IMO @LuisMendo answer is elegant and I would go with it, but if you don't have `repelem`, an alternative is to use `cellfun` and then `cell2mat`:

```
data = {[1,2,3], [4,5], [6], [7,8,9,10]}
% output = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4]
output = cell2mat(cellfun(@(d,i) i*ones(1,numel(d)),data,...
    num2cell(1:numel(data)),'UniformOutput',0) )
```

Comment: Good idea. Or, perhaps simpler, `cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) repmat(k,1,numel(data{k})), 1:numel(data), 'UniformOutput', false))`

Comment: repelem is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately I'm on R2012a. This solution works great though, thanks!

Comment: @RyanWaite Consider accepting it in that case. There's a tick mark on the upper left. And welcome to Stack Overflow!