# How to generate continuous numbers with repetitive increment in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I would like to generate a continuous number with repetitive increment, for example,from 1 to 3. with a repetitive increment of 1 (x 5). so the output will be.

output =

```
[1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3]
```

five repetition of 1, then five repetition of 2 and so on.

I tried this code:

```
a = [1:1:3]
for i = a(:,1:end)
    disp(i+zeros(5,1))
end
```

I got the same result, however, I can't put the output in one column. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `reshape(repmat(a, 5, 1), 5*numel(a), 1)`

Comment: `kron(a',ones(5,1))`

Comment: @HansHirse how about i want to extend up to N numbers? for example from 1 to 100?

Comment: @Ralden123 Go for [Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457424/11089932) (the old [golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) fanatic), you can set up your `n` there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat copies of array elements: Run-length decoding in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/repeat-copies-of-array-elements-run-length-decoding-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
n = 3; % number of distinct numbers
s = 2; % starting number
m = 5; % number of repetitions of each number
```

A couple of options are

```
output = repelem(s:s+n-1,m);
```

or

```
output = ceil(s-1+1/m:1/m:s+n-1);
```

Comment: This is good! however what if I want to start with n numbers? for example 10-100?

Comment: @Ralden123 That was an easy one :-) Glad I could help!