# Element-wise array replication according to a count

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat, run-length-encoding, elementwise-operations

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947889/element-wise-array-replication-in-matlab), but I would like to replicate each element according to a count specified in a second array of the same size.

An example of this, say I had an array `v = [3 1 9 4]`, I want to use `rep = [2 3 1 5]` to replicate the first element 2 times, the second three times, and so on to get `[3 3 1 1 1 9 4 4 4 4 4]`.

So far I'm using a simple loop to get the job done. This is what I started with:

```
vv = [];
for i=1:numel(v)
    vv = [vv repmat(v(i),1,rep(i))];
end
```

I managed to improve by preallocating space:

```
vv = zeros(1,sum(rep));
c = cumsum([1 rep]);
for i=1:numel(v)
    vv(c(i):c(i)+rep(i)-1) = repmat(v(i),1,rep(i));
end
```

However I still feel there has to be a more clever way to do this... Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/matlab-array-manipulation

Comment: @Doresoom: I thought I had answered a question like this before, but couldn't find it. I finally hunted it down at the same time as you. The title and tags were quite different, which was what made it a little tough to find.

Comment: if anyone comes here looking for a numpy solution, check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one way I like to accomplish this:

```
>> index = zeros(1,sum(rep));
>> index(cumsum([1 rep(1:end-1)])) = 1;

index =

     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0

>> index = cumsum(index)

index =

     1     1     2     2     2     3     4     4     4     4     4

>> vv = v(index)

vv =

     3     3     1     1     1     9     4     4     4     4     4
```

This works by first creating an index vector of zeroes the same length as the final count of all the values. By performing a cumulative sum of the `rep` vector with the last element removed and a 1 placed at the start, I get a vector of indices into `index` showing where the groups of replicated values will begin. These points are marked with ones. When a cumulative sum is performed on `index`, I get a final index vector that I can use to index into `v` to create the vector of heterogeneously-replicated values.

Comment: could you add some comments of how this works?

Comment: @Nathan: Already ahead of ya. =)

Comment: definitely a clever way of using `cumsum`.. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful, this solution works only if all elements of `rep` are positive. If you don't want to repeat some elements by setting some elements of `rep` to zeros, it will fail. `v = [3 1 9 4]` and `rep = [2 3 1 0]` result into `[3 3 1 1 1 9 4]`, giving an extra element.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the list of possible solutions, consider this one:

```
vv = cellfun(@(a,b)repmat(a,1,b), num2cell(v), num2cell(rep), 'UniformOutput',0);
vv = [vv{:}];
```

This is much slower than the one by [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382319/matlab-element-wise-array-replication-according-to-a-count/2382382#2382382)..

Comment: You could actually use ARRAYFUN and avoid the calls to NUM2CELL, but it would still be *much* slower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/matlab-array-manipulation/1975835#1975835.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to **run-length decode**. A high level reliable/vectorized utility is the [FEX submission `rude()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6436):

```
% example inputs
counts = [2, 3, 1];
values = [24,3,30];
```

the result

```
rude(counts, values)
ans =
    24    24     3     3     3    30
```

Note that this function performs the opposite operation as well, i.e. **run-length encodes** a vector or in other words returns `values` and the corresponding `counts`.

Answer (score 0):

`accumarray` function can be used to make the code work if zeros exit in `rep` array

```
function vv = repeatElements(v, rep)
index = accumarray(cumsum(rep)'+1, 1);
vv = v(cumsum(index(1:end-1))+1);
end
```

This works similar to solution of gnovice, except that indices are accumulated instead being assigned to 1. This allows to skip some indices (3 and 6 in the example below) and remove corresponding elements from the output.

```
>> v = [3 1 42 9 4 42];
>> rep = [2 3 0 1 5 0];
>> index = accumarray(cumsum(rep)'+1, 1)'

index =

     0     0     1     0     0     2     1     0     0     0     0     2

>> cumsum(index(1:end-1))+1

ans =

     1     1     2     2     2     4     5     5     5     5     5

>> vv = v(cumsum(index(1:end-1))+1)

vv =

     3     3     1     1     1     9     4     4     4     4     4
```