# how to repeat element matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat

How to repeat

```
A = [ 1 2 ; 
      3 4 ]
```

repeated by

```
B = [ 1 2 ; 
      2 1 ]
```

So I want my answer like matrix C:

```
C = [ 1 2 2; 
      3 3 4 ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the logic? please explain

Comment: @Andrey: I assume that where there's a "2" in `B`, we want to repeat the value of `A` twice along columns.

Comment: @Jonas That actually makes sense!

Comment: related questions: [MATLAB Array Manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1975772/97160), [Element-wise array replication according to a count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2382319/97160)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this simple, I assume that you're only going to add more columns, and that you've checked that you have the same number of columns for each row.

Then it becomes a simple combination of repeating elements and reshaping.

*EDIT* I've modified the code so that it also works if A and B are 3D arrays.

```
%# get the number of rows from A, transpose both
%# A and B so that linear indexing works
[nRowsA,~,nValsA] = size(A);
A = permute(A,[2 1 3]);
B = permute(B,[2 1 3]);

%# create an index vector from B 
%# so that we know what to repeat
nRep = sum(B(:));

repIdx = zeros(1,nRep);
repIdxIdx = cumsum([1 B(1:end-1)]);
repIdx(repIdxIdx) = 1;
repIdx = cumsum(repIdx);

%# assemble the array C
C = A(repIdx);
C = permute(reshape(C,[],nRowsA,nValsA),[2 1 3]);

C =
     1     2     2
     3     3     4
```

Comment: The +1 is for understanding the cryptic logic of the question :)

Comment: @EitanT: I saw that there was "repeat" in the title, and that we should use B to find out how to repeat elements from A. I actually found it pretty obvious. Thanks for the upvote, anyway :)

Comment: @jonas : how if i wanna do like with more than value of matrix A and B?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: I don't quite understand. Can you make an example, please?

Comment: @jonas: i mean that, actually Matrix A have more than one val, example (val (;,;,1), val (;,;,2),...). matrix B also have more than one val. so I felt difficult when I used your logic, specially in cumsum([1 B(1:end-1)]);. do you understrand jonas??

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: The code works for nd-arrays with a few modifications. See my edited code

Comment: @jonas: thank you so much jonas for your help. ok I will try to use your code. and if I have any question, I will ask you again. :)

Comment: @jonas: jonasss, thanks you so much for your code. it helped me so much!!. jonas, can i know your email?? so that i can ask you anytime if I want??

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting/accepting it. Also, I suggest you ask your questions on StackOverflow, since it is much more likely that they get answered in a timely fashion.

Comment: @jonas: thanks you very much jonas. and maybe after this, I will ask you again Mr. Jonas. So I hope You will give your idea as soon as possible yah. hehe

Answer (score 6):

Just for the fun of it, another solution making use of arrayfun:

```
res = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(a,b) ones(b,1).*a, A', B', 'uniformoutput', false))'
```

This results in:

```
res =

     1     2     2
     3     3     4
```

Comment: +1: you consistently produce nice really neat one-liners, sir :)