# Retrieving array elements with an array of frequencies in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of numbers, `a`. I have a second array, `b`, specifying how many times I want to retrieve the corresponding element in `a`. How can this be achieved? The ordering of the output is not important in this case.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
b = np.array([1,0,3,2,0])

# desired output = [0,2,2,2,3,3]
# i.e. [a[0], a[2], a[2], a[2], a[3], a[3] ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Element-wise array replication according to a count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382319/element-wise-array-replication-according-to-a-count)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats exactly what `np.arange(5).repeat([1,0,3,2,0])` does.

Answer (score 0):

A really inefficient way to do that is this one :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
b = np.array([1,0,3,2,0])

res = []
i = 0
for val in b:
    for aa in range(val):
        res.append(a[i])
    i += 1
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it:

```
res = []
for i in xrange(len(b)):
    for j in xrange(b[i]):
        out.append(a[i])

res = np.array(res)  # optional
```