# Split a vector according to a defined sequence

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, sequence

Can anyone suggest a way in which it is possible to perform operations on a vector according to a predetermined sequence - for example I have a vector of different values, M, which is <8760x1> in size. I have another vector with a sequence of numbers, P, (size <300x1>) and this sequence sums to 8760. I would like to use these P values to index the vector M and find the product of each index.

An example to make this clearer:

M = [1,2,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,2];

P = [2,2,4,2];

Result = [3,6,15,6]

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Peter.S.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. To use P as an index to M use M(P). That will give you [2, 2, 2, 2] in your example. Where does the product come from?

Comment: Apologies I have used the term index incorrectly. I wanted to find Result which gives the value of M(1,1)+M(1,2) =3, then M(1,3)+M(1,4) =6, then M(1,5)+M(1,6)+M(1,7)+M(1,8)=15 and M(1,9)+ M(1,10) =6.

Comment: The following codes can be used to solve this: M = [1,2,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,2];
P = [2,2,4,2];
id2=cumsum(P);
id1=[1 id2(1:end-1)+1];
for k=1:numel(id1)
  Result(k)=sum(M(id1(k):id2(k)));
end
%or

id2=cumsum(P);
id1=[1 id2(1:end-1)+1];
Result=arrayfun(@(x,y) sum(M(x:y)),id1,id2)

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way based on [acummarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and a clever way to make an index vector using [cumsum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html). Given the two vectors:

```
M = [1,2,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,2];
P = [2,2,4,2];
```

Create a vector of unique indices per frequency value in `P` (following this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382319/element-wise-array-replication-according-to-a-count) post):

```
numM = sum(P);
index = zeros(numM, 1);
index(cumsum([1 P(1:end-1)])) = 1;
index = cumsum(index);

>> index'
ans =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     3     3     4     4
```

Apply `accumarray()` using the constructed index vector and the vector of values:

```
result = accumarray(index, M);

>> result'
ans =
     3     6    15     6
```