# Populating all the values of a vector with values from another vector at places from still another vector

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors representing the edges and levels some continuous data (this is simulated at the moment).

```
edges = [50, 120, 170, 200, 220, 224, 250]
levels = [24,3,30,0,36,0]
```

How would I create a vector that has 24 for the first 50 entries, 3 for the subsequent 120 etc?

I've tried

```
psd = zeros(1,250)
psd(edges) = levels
```

but this just puts a single value at the relevant position - it's not quite what I want.

Comment: `edges` and `levels` are not the same size. Don't you forgot a `0` somewhere? Also your question is not very clear: what is the length of `psd`? Considering your try, it will be 250; but you mention _3 for the subsequent 120_, so I understand that the length of `psd` would be 50+120+...+250 instead. Could you please precise which possibility you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and code don't quite match. Do you want psd to have 250 elements or 1234 (`sum(edges)`, as your use of subsequent would imply)?  If it's the latter, you can simply modify `edges = cumsum(edges)`. Secondly, you don't have enough levels for the given edges.

Here's a solution without the use of loops.

```
edges = [50, 120, 170, 200, 220, 224, 250];
levels = [24,3,30,0,36,0,nan]; % padded with nan for equal length
idxs = length(levels) - sum(bsxfun(@(x,y) x < y,1:max(edges),edges'+1))+1;
pds = levels(idxs)
```

Or even simpler:

```
idxs = zeros(1,max(edges));
idxs(edges(1:end-1)+1) = 1;
psd = levels(cumsum(idxs)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little solution, if `edges` is really the edges of your intervals:

Expand the vector `levels` with 0 as a first element:

```
levels = [0, 24, 3, 30, 0, 36, 0];
```

Then you can do the following:

```
psd = zeros(1,250);
psd(edges(2:end)-1) = diff(levels);
psd = cumsum(psd);
```

You put at the interval limits the offset betwwen two consecutive values, 0 elsewhere. When summing up, you have what you expect.

Comment: @Eitan T: could you precise your mind please? I have 24 for the 50 first values, then 3 till index 120, etc. What do you mean with the correct values?

Comment: My bad, copy-paste error.

Comment: No pb, comments and corrections are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Involves a loop but it should be OK. Also, your `edges` and `levels` need to be of equal length.

```
v = [];
for i = 1:numel(edges)
    v = [v;level(i)*ones(edges(i),1)];
end
```

Here's a more efficient version which takes care of the allocation overhead.

```
v = zeros(sum(edges),1);
c = [0 cumsum(edges)];
for i = 1:numel(edges)-1
    v( c(i)+1:c(i+1) ) = levels(i)*ones(edges(i),1);
end
```

Just remember ; loops aren't always evil in today's MATLAB. Sometimes, it's the simplest (and clearest) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this run-length decoding utility [FEX `rude()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6436), which implements the approach showed by [Bentoy13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507014/bentoy13):

```
% example inputs
edges  = [2, 3, 1];
levels = [24,3,30];
```

the result

```
rude(edges, levels)
ans =
    24    24     3     3     3    30
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382319/element-wise-array-replication-according-to-a-count#2382382) by [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) you can use this:

```
psd = levels(cumsum(sparse(1,cumsum([1 edges(1:end-1)]),1,1,sum(edges))));
```

To make it easier you can create an anonymous function and resuse it instead:

```
populate = @(L,E) L(cumsum(sparse(1,cumsum([1 E(1:end-1)]),1,1,sum(E))));
psd = popultae(levels, edges);
```