# Changing values in one MatLab matrix based on ranges stored in a second matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Elements of a column matrix of non-sequential numbers (`sourceData`) should have their values incremented if their index positions lie between certain values as defined in a second column matrix (`triggerIndices`) which lists the indices sequentially.

This can be easily done with a `for`-loop but can it be done in a vectorized way?

```
%// Generation of example data follows
sourceData = randi(1e3,100,1);

%// sourceData = 1:1:1000; %// Would show more clearly what is happening
triggerIndices = randperm(length(sourceData),15);
triggerIndices = sort(triggerIndices);

%// End of example data generation

%// Code to be vectorized follows

increment = 75;
addOn = 100;
for index = 1:1:length(triggerIndices)-1
    sourceData(triggerIndices(index):1:triggerIndices(index+1)-1) = ...
        sourceData(triggerIndices(index):1:triggerIndices(index+1)-1) + addOn;
    addOn = addOn + increment;
end

sourceData(triggerIndices(end):1:end) = ....
    sourceData(triggerIndices(end):1:end) + addOn;
%// End of code to be vectorized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing everything with:

```
vals = sparse(triggerIndices, 1, increment, numel(sourceData), 1);
vals(triggerIndices(1)) = addOn;
sourceData(:) = sourceData(:) + cumsum(vals);
```

This is basically a variant of run-length decoding shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2382319/1336150#2382382).

Comment: Here's a slightly simpler version of the same thing: `incArray = zeros(size(sourceData)); incArray(triggerIndices) = increment; incArray(triggerIndices(1)) = addOn; sourceData = cumsum(incArray) + sourceData;`

Comment: Thanks @EitanT but I'm getting the error "Error using reshape. To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change." when I try those statements.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the suggestion. I've simplified it even further :)

Comment: @RossJDonaldson Please try the amended answer.

Comment: Nice ;)  I forgot about `sparse`.  Except I think you want `vals(triggerIndices(1)) = addOn;`