# Create vector with predetermined number of certain elements

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a problem where I have a set of numbers, eg; [3 5 9] and for each of these numbers an amount of occurences eg. [2 1 5]. Now i would like to create a vector containing these numbers the prespecified amount of times, so for the example the result would be [3 3 5 9 9 9 9 9 ]. Is there an elegant way to do this in MATLAB, that is, vectorized?

Comment: here's another http://stackoverflow.com/q/2382319/97160, and probably many more questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repelem` is the function you want

```
a = [3,5,9]; b = [2,1,5]; c = repelem(a,b)

c =

     3     3     5     9     9     9     9     9
```