# Upsample by an integral factor in matlab without applying any filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sample

> **Duplicate:**
>   [Element-wise array replication in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947889/element-wise-array-replication-in-matlab)

How do I upsample a vector by an integral factor without applying any filtering to the upsampled data?

Basically I e.g. want to upsample a vector three times from

```
[1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 ]
```

to:

```
[1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 ]
```

Comment: Note that in the above example you *are* applying a filter, with coefficients [1 1 1]. To upsample without filtering you would need to insert zeroes between each sample, I.e. 1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 0

Comment: @Amro: You are right, the answer to that questions answers my question completely. Mark as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found out myself:

```
resample(samples, upsample_rate, 1, 0);
```

The fourth parameter tells [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/resample.html) to use a weighted sum of 0 samples for the filter it applies to the upsampled data. Which effectively nullifies the filter.

Comment: it is shifted by 1. The last element is 0 and there are only two 1s at the start.