# Interleaved repmat

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Element-wise array replication in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947889/element-wise-array-replication-in-matlab)

I have a `m x 1` vector that I would like to repeat `n` times to create a `(m*n)x1` vector. If I use `repmat`, I get something like

```
>> V = [a;b;c];
>> repmat(V,2,1) % n = 2, m = 3
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

What would be a one-line (and hopefully fast) way of getting the vector

```
[a;a;a;b;b;b;c;c;c]
```

for arbitrary `n` and `m`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
V=[ 1;2;3];
reshape(repmat(V',3,1),[],1)

ans =

     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     3
     3
     3
```

Comment: Just great! Thanks for the help.