# MATLAB - Returning a matrix of sums of elements corresponding to the same kind

Tags: matlab, sum, sumifs

**Overview**

An `n×m` matrix `A` and an `n×1` vector `Date` are the inputs of the function `S = sumdate(A,Date)`.

The function returns an `n×m` vector `S` such that all rows in `S` correspond to the sum of the rows of `A` from the same date.

For example, if

```
A = [1  2  7  3  7  3  4  1  9
     6  4  3  0 -1  2  8  7  5]';
Date = [161012 161223 161223 170222 160801 170222 161012 161012 161012]';
```

Then I would expect the returned matrix `S` is

```
S = [15 9 9 6 7 6 15 15 15;
    26 7 7 2 -1 2 26 26 26]';
```

- Because the elements `Date(2)` and `Date(3)` are the same, we have

  1. `S(2,1)` and `S(3,1)` are both equal to the sum of `A(2,1)` and `A(3,1)`
  2. `S(2,2)` and `S(3,2)` are both equal to the sum of `A(2,2)` and `A(3,2)`.
- Because the elements `Date(1)`, `Date(7)`, `Date(8)` and `Date(9)` are the same, we have

  1. `S(1,1)`, `S(7,1)`, `S(8,1)`, `S(9,1)` equal the sum of `A(1,1)`, `A(7,1)`, `A(8,1)`, `A(9,1)`
  2. `S(1,2)`, `S(7,2)`, `S(8,2)`, `S(9,2)` equal the sum of `A(1,2)`, `A(7,2)`, `A(8,2)`, `A(9,2)`

The same for `S([4,6],1)` and `S([4,6],2)`

As the element `Date(5)` does not repeat, so `S(5,1) = A(5,1) = 7` and `S(5,2) = A(5,2) = -1`.

---

**The code I have written so far**

Here is my try on the code for this task.

```
function S = sumdate(A,Date)
    S = A; %Pre-assign S as a matrix in the same size of A.
    Dlist = unique(Date); %Sort out a non-repeating list from Date
    for J = 1 : length(Dlist)
        loc = (Date == Dlist(J)); %Compute a logical indexing vector for locating the J-th element in Dlist
        S(loc,:) = repmat(sum(S(loc,:)),sum(loc),1); %Replace the located rows of S by the sum of them
    end
end
```

I tested it on my computer using `A` and `Date` with these attributes:

```
size(A) = [33055    400];
size(Date) = [33055    1];
length(unique(Date)) = 2645;
```

It took my PC about 1.25 seconds to perform the task.

This task is performed hundreds of thousands of times in my project, therefore my code is too time-consuming. I think the performance will be boosted up if I can eliminate the for-loop above.

I have found some built-in functions which do special types of sums like `accumarray` or `cumsum`, but I still do not have any ideas on how to eliminate the for-loop.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Note: you should use `.'` to transpose matrices, not the complex conjugate transpose `'`

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit and advice. You are right, I should use `.'` instead because I do not need any conjugates in that case that the input contains complex numbers.

Comment: No problem, I ended up doing the edit for you, but in future try and use `code formatting` instead of **bold formatting** when you have code within your text, it makes things a lot clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), but you'll need to generate a set of row and column subscripts into `A` to do it. Here's how:

```
[~, ~, index] = unique(Date);  % Get indices of unique dates
subs = [repmat(index, size(A, 2), 1) ...         % repmat to create row subscript
        repelem((1:size(A, 2)).', size(A, 1))];  % repelem to create column subscript
S = accumarray(subs, A(:));    % Reshape A into column vector for accumarray
S = S(index, :);               % Use index to expand S to original size of A

S =

    15    26
     9     7
     9     7
     6     2
     7    -1
     6     2
    15    26
    15    26
    15    26
```

**Note #1:** This will use more memory than your for loop solution (`subs` will have twice the number of element as `A`), but may give you a significant speed-up.

**Note #2:** If you are using a version of MATLAB older than R2015a, you won't have [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html). Instead you can replace that line using [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) (or one of the other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1947889/52738)):

```
kron((1:size(A, 2)).', ones(size(A, 1), 1))
```

Comment: If you don't have `repelem` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/repeat-copies-of-array-elements-run-length-decoding-in-matlab)

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I added a note for that.

Comment: My version is 2016a and I have enough RAM for it, so the solution is absolutely fine for me. Your solution is simple and efficient. Thank you very much.