# What is an alternative to repmat for creating a 1D array of repeated values?

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, matrix, optimization

I have a grid that I want to store x and y coordinates for in 1D arrays. It is orthogonal so that x values are the same at each y in the grid, and vice versa. I've recently tried to vectorize the procedure and am using a `repmat`-`reshape` combination to achieve this. I heard that `repmat` is not the best, and wondered if there are *faster* alternatives to this same procedure.

For example, if the grid contains 3 nodes in the x direction (`nX = 3`) and 4 in the y direction (`nY = 4`), and their "template" values are as follows:

```
xTemplate =   [0    0.5000    1.0000]
yTemplate =   [0    0.3333    0.6667    1.0000]
```

Then the values for the entire grid would look like:

```
xArray =
     0    0.5000    1.0000
     0    0.5000    1.0000
     0    0.5000    1.0000
     0    0.5000    1.0000
```

and

```
yArray =
     0         0         0
     0.3333    0.3333    0.3333
     0.6667    0.6667    0.6667
     1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Ultimately, I want them to be contained in 1D arrays, where the values are stored in order from `1` to `nX*nY`, in other words where

`iVec = nX*(jArray - 1) + iArray`

So that they look as follows:

```
[xVec yVec] = 
     0         0
0.5000         0
1.0000         0
     0    0.3333
0.5000    0.3333
1.0000    0.3333
     0    0.6667
0.5000    0.6667
1.0000    0.6667
     0    1.0000
0.5000    1.0000
1.0000    1.0000
```

Currently, I have the following code to achieve this, but am wondering if there are other ways to increase the speed here:

```
nX = 3;
nY = 4;

xTemplate = linspace(0,1,nX); 
xArray    = repmat(xTemplate, nY, 1);
xVec      = reshape(xArray', [nX*nY 1]);

yTemplate = linspace(0,1,nY); 
yArray    = repmat(yTemplate, nX, 1)';
yVec      = reshape(yArray' , [nX*nY 1]);
```

What are some alternatives to this that might increase speed? Is there a simpler approach that omits creating `xArray` and `yArray` which are only intermediate and not necessary? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The two-column matrix you ultimately want to obtain can be generated using any of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) with `vectors = {yTemplate, xTemplate}` and applying `fliplr` to the result. (This is also valid for more than two vectors)

Comment: thanks for that. It seems as though `meshgrid` is faster though, would that be something I did wrong?

Comment: I would expect plain `meshgrid` to quite fast here. My linked answer essentially uses that (well, the equivalent `ndgrid`), plus some additional code. Are you timing with `tic`/ `toc` or with `timeit`? The latter is more accurate

Comment: I've been using tic-toc. How does the other work better for timing, ooc?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18955502/2586922)'s a nice explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the code shorter, you can use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) for this:

```
nX = 3;
nY = 4;

[YY, XX] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,nX), linspace(0,1,nY));
xVec = XX(:);
yVec = YY(:);
```

Though this probably doesn't improve performance...

Comment: This is actually the fastest one yet according to some tests

Comment: You need to swap your input arguments to `meshgrid`, too.

Comment: I noticed that as well. It's a bit confusing for readability to have `[Y,X] = meshgrid(y,x)`, but it's concise and fast enough that I might stick with it/

Comment: @teepee: How did you do the timing? Using [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) is generally more accurate than [`tic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html)/[`toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html).

Comment: I did use tic-toc. Oops. How far off is tic-toc usually?

Comment: @teepee: Some comparisons [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html). `timeit` takes the median over multiple runs and accounts for first-time costs. `tic/toc` also isn't recommended for fast code (less than 0.1 sec).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily build `xVec` using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) by just reshaping `xTemplate` to a column vector first using the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) (or a [nonconjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) `.'`):

```
xVec = repmat(xTemplate(:), [nY 1]);
```

And `yVec` can be built just as easily using [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) (present since R2015a):

```
yVec = repelem(yTemplate(:), nX);
```

If you're using an older version of MATLAB, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1947889/52738) gives a number of alternatives to `repelem`.

### Timing:

I was curious, so I decided to time all the solutions thus far (with minor changes to each to make them more equivalent tests). Here are some typical timing results (using [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html), MATLAB R2016b, Windows 7), with the test code below:

```
>> grid_timing(3, 4)
teepee:  7.09515e-06  % Longest
gnovice: 4.66416e-06  % Shortest
Aero:    4.90961e-06
Dev-iL:  6.23629e-06

>> grid_timing(100, 100)
teepee:  4.41746e-05  % Longest
gnovice: 1.65685e-05  % Shortest
Aero:    3.00774e-05
Dev-iL:  2.81186e-05
```

The differences were often very small, even for larger grids, but my solution tends to be slightly faster.

Test code:

```
function grid_timing(nX, nY)
  [xt, yt] = teepee_grid(nX, nY);
  [xg, yg] = gnovice_grid(nX, nY);
  [xA, yA] = Aero_grid(nX, nY);
  [xD, yD] = DeviL_grid(nX, nY);
  if ~isequal(xt, xg, xA, xD) || ...
     ~isequal(yt, yg, yA, yD)
    disp('Solutions don''t match!');
  end
  fprintf('teepee:  %g\n', timeit(@() teepee_grid(nX, nY), 2));
  fprintf('gnovice: %g\n', timeit(@() gnovice_grid(nX, nY), 2));
  fprintf('Aero:    %g\n', timeit(@() Aero_grid(nX, nY), 2));
  fprintf('Dev-iL:  %g\n', timeit(@() DeviL_grid(nX, nY), 2));
end
function [xVec, yVec] = gnovice_grid(nX, nY)
  xVec = repmat(linspace(0,1,nX).', [nY 1]);
  yVec = repelem(linspace(0,1,nY).', nX);
end
function [xVec, yVec] = Aero_grid(nX, nY)
  yVec = linspace(0,1,nY).*ones(nX,1);
  xVec = linspace(0,1,nX).'.*ones(1,nY);
  yVec = yVec(:);
  xVec = xVec(:);
end
function [xVec, yVec] = DeviL_grid(nX, nY)
  [YY, XX] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,nY), linspace(0,1,nX));
  xVec = XX(:);
  yVec = YY(:);
end
function [xVec, yVec] = teepee_grid(nX, nY)
  xArray    = repmat(linspace(0,1,nX), nY, 1);
  xVec      = reshape(xArray', [nX*nY 1]);
  yArray    = repmat(linspace(0,1,nY), nX, 1)';
  yVec      = reshape(yArray' , [nX*nY 1]);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that help, that is a really concise way to write it. However it doesn't seem to be faster so I'm wondering if there's any other tricks to add perhaps?

Comment: @teepee: How much time is this actually taking? I can't imagine this takes long enough to be a bottleneck in your code. Trying to speed this up seems like a micro-optimization.

Comment: It has a larger effect when creating grids of thousands of nodes essentially, but I think you're right that it shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Comment: That is sweet. Very nice look at it there. Thanks for doing that. Also, I noticed that using `reshape` in my function caused it to crash compared with your (:) operations for very large grids. How does the memory treatment work differently in those cases, ooc?

Comment: @teepee: The memory issue may simply be due to the fact that you are storing some intermediate values (i.e. `xArray` and `yArray`) which may be taking up more memory, and it just so happens that MATLAB runs out of memory during the reshape operation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using implicit expansion in newer version of Matlab:

```
yVec = yTemplate .* ones(nX,1);
xVec = xTemplate' .* ones(1,nY);

yVec = yVec(:);
xVec = xVec(:);
```

Comment: I didn't know about that implicit expansion stuff; thanks for that!

Comment: I didn't either until a few weeks ago and now I use it all time.  I can eliminate a bunch of `bsxfun` calls from my code.